# The presented password is invalid Symfony 4

Tags: forms, symfony, passwords

I have built a modification password form.

```
class ChangePasswordType extends AbstractType {
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('plainPassword', RepeatedType::class, array(
            'type' => PasswordType::class,
            'required' => true,
            'invalid_message' => 'The password fields must match.',
            'first_options'  => array('label' => false, 'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'nouveau mot de passe')),
            'second_options' => array('label' => false, 'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'confirmer mot de passe')),
        ))
        ->add('valider', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'VALIDER'))
    ;
}
```

}

my controller:

```
             if ($form_change_password->isSubmitted() && $form_change_password->isValid()) {
                $password = $passwordEncoder->encodePassword($user, $user->getPlainPassword());
                $user->setPassword($password);

                $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

                // perform some action...
                $entityManager->flush();
                return $this->redirectToRoute('connexion');
            }
```

I correctly update the encrypted password in the database using the bcrypt param of my security file, but the problem is that when I enter my login and password it is always "invalid credentials"...
I have checked the password is correctly updated each time I fill in the changePassword form...

But it looks like my password is not the one I have entered in the form..why?

Thanks in advance for your help:)

Comment: have you tried to use security:encode-password <yourpass>. If that works, probably the problem is on how you handle the form.

Comment: There is full tutorial on symfony page how to do it https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/doctrine/registration_form.html#registration-password-max

Comment: Thank you robert i saw my mistake with it